# Twilio SMS Marketing node . command won't start app gives throw error mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, module, twilio

I've been attempting to install the twilio sms marketing example app (https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/marketing-notifications-node/tree/master) . I've installed mongodb and mongo and have been able to run them without any problems. The problems occur when I try to run the `node .` command. I receive throw errors. Here is the error I receive when I try to use `node .` in the project directory.

```
    MacBook-Pro:marketing-notifications-node-master user$ node .
        module.js:471
            throw err;
            ^

        Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/$USER/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:8:52)
            at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        MacBook-Pro:marketing-notifications-node-master $USER$
```

I really need help to figure this out.

I've tried

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install

npm install
```

output:

```
    /Users/$USER/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /Users/$USER/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/Users/$USER/.npm-packages/lib
└─┬ npm@4.3.0 
  ├── abbrev@1.0.9 
  ├── ansi-regex@2.1.1 
  ├── ansicolors@0.3.2 
  ├── ansistyles@0.1.3 
  ├── aproba@1.1.1 
  ├── archy@1.0.0 
  ├── asap@2.0.5 
  ├── chownr@1.0.1 
  ├── cmd-shim@2.0.2 
  ├─┬ columnify@1.5.4 
  │ └─┬ wcwidth@1.0.0 
  │   └─┬ defaults@1.0.3 
  │     └── clone@1.0.2 
  ├─┬ config-chain@1.1.11 
  │ └── proto-list@1.2.4 
  ├── debuglog@1.0.1 
  ├── dezalgo@1.0.3 
  ├── editor@1.0.0 
  ├── fs-vacuum@1.2.9 
  ├── fs-write-stream-atomic@1.0.8 
  ├── fstream@1.0.10 
  ├─┬ fstream-npm@1.2.0 
  │ └─┬ fstream-ignore@1.0.5 
  │   └─┬ minimatch@3.0.3 
  │     └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
  │       ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
  │       └── concat-map@0.0.1 
  ├─┬ glob@7.1.1 
  │ ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.3 
  │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
  │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
  │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
  │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
  ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11 
  ├── has-unicode@2.0.1 
  ├── hosted-git-info@2.2.0 
  ├── iferr@0.1.5 
  ├── imurmurhash@0.1.4 
  ├── inflight@1.0.6 
  ├── inherits@2.0.3 
  ├── ini@1.3.4 
  ├─┬ init-package-json@1.9.4 
  │ ├─┬ glob@6.0.4 
  │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.3 
  │ │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
  │ │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
  │ │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
  │ │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.0 
  │ └── promzard@0.3.0 
  ├─┬ JSONStream@1.3.0 
  │ ├── jsonparse@1.2.0 
  │ └── through@2.3.8 
  ├── lazy-property@1.0.0 
  ├── lockfile@1.0.3 
  ├── lodash._baseindexof@3.1.0 
  ├─┬ lodash._baseuniq@4.6.0 
  │ ├── lodash._createset@4.0.3 
  │ └── lodash._root@3.0.1 
  ├── lodash._bindcallback@3.0.1 
  ├── lodash._cacheindexof@3.0.2 
  ├── lodash._createcache@3.1.2 
  ├── lodash._getnative@3.9.1 
  ├── lodash.clonedeep@4.5.0 
  ├── lodash.restparam@3.6.1 
  ├── lodash.union@4.6.0 
  ├── lodash.uniq@4.5.0 
  ├── lodash.without@4.4.0 
  ├─┬ mississippi@1.3.0 
  │ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.6.0 
  │ │ └── typedarray@0.0.6 
  │ ├─┬ duplexify@3.5.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ end-of-stream@1.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── once@1.3.3 
  │ │ └── stream-shift@1.0.0 
  │ ├─┬ end-of-stream@1.1.0 
  │ │ └── once@1.3.3 
  │ ├── flush-write-stream@1.0.2 
  │ ├── from2@2.3.0 
  │ ├─┬ parallel-transform@1.1.0 
  │ │ └── cyclist@0.2.2 
  │ ├── pump@1.0.2 
  │ ├── pumpify@1.3.5 
  │ ├─┬ stream-each@1.2.0 
  │ │ └── stream-shift@1.0.0 
  │ └─┬ through2@2.0.3 
  │   └── xtend@4.0.1 
  ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
  │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
  ├─┬ node-gyp@3.5.0 
  │ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.3 
  │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
  │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
  │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
  │ └── nopt@3.0.6 
  ├─┬ nopt@4.0.1 
  │ └─┬ osenv@0.1.4 
  │   ├── os-homedir@1.0.2 
  │   └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
  ├── normalize-git-url@3.0.2 
  ├─┬ normalize-package-data@2.3.5 
  │ └─┬ is-builtin-module@1.0.0 
  │   └── builtin-modules@1.1.1 
  ├── npm-cache-filename@1.0.2 
  ├── npm-install-checks@3.0.0 
  ├── npm-package-arg@4.2.0 
  ├─┬ npm-registry-client@7.4.5 
  │ └─┬ concat-stream@1.5.2 
  │   ├─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6 
  │   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
  │   │ ├── isarray@1.0.0 
  │   │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
  │   │ ├── string_decoder@0.10.31 
  │   │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
  │   └── typedarray@0.0.6 
  ├── npm-user-validate@0.1.5 
  ├─┬ npmlog@4.0.2 
  │ ├─┬ are-we-there-yet@1.1.2 
  │ │ └── delegates@1.0.0 
  │ ├── console-control-strings@1.1.0 
  │ ├─┬ gauge@2.7.2 
  │ │ ├── object-assign@4.1.0 
  │ │ ├── signal-exit@3.0.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ string-width@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0 
  │ │ │ └─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
  │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├── supports-color@0.2.0 
  │ │ └── wide-align@1.1.0 
  │ └── set-blocking@2.0.0 
  ├── once@1.4.0 
  ├── opener@1.4.2 
  ├─┬ osenv@0.1.4 
  │ ├── os-homedir@1.0.2 
  │ └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
  ├── path-is-inside@1.0.2 
  ├─┬ read@1.0.7 
  │ └── mute-stream@0.0.5 
  ├── read-cmd-shim@1.0.1 
  ├─┬ read-installed@4.0.3 
  │ └── util-extend@1.0.3 
  ├─┬ read-package-json@2.0.4 
  │ ├─┬ glob@6.0.4 
  │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.3 
  │ │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
  │ │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
  │ │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
  │ │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.0 
  │ └─┬ json-parse-helpfulerror@1.0.3 
  │   └── jju@1.3.0 
  ├── read-package-tree@5.1.5 
  ├─┬ readable-stream@2.2.2 
  │ ├── buffer-shims@1.0.0 
  │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
  │ ├── isarray@1.0.0 
  │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
  │ ├── string_decoder@0.10.31 
  │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
  ├── readdir-scoped-modules@1.0.2 
  ├── realize-package-specifier@3.0.3 
  ├─┬ request@2.79.0 
  │ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0 
  │ ├── aws4@1.5.0 
  │ ├── caseless@0.11.0 
  │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5 
  │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
  │ ├── extend@3.0.0 
  │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1 
  │ ├─┬ form-data@2.1.2 
  │ │ └── asynckit@0.4.0 
  │ ├─┬ har-validator@2.0.6 
  │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3 
  │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
  │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
  │ │ │ ├── has-ansi@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0 
  │ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ is-my-json-valid@2.15.0 
  │ │ │ ├── generate-function@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ generate-object-property@1.2.0 
  │ │ │ │ └── is-property@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ ├── jsonpointer@4.0.0 
  │ │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1 
  │ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
  │ │   └── pinkie@2.0.4 
  │ ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3 
  │ │ ├── boom@2.10.1 
  │ │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5 
  │ │ ├── hoek@2.16.3 
  │ │ └── sntp@1.0.9 
  │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1 
  │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.3.1 
  │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.3 
  │ │ │ └── verror@1.3.6 
  │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.10.1 
  │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3 
  │ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
  │ │   ├── bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.0 
  │ │   ├── dashdash@1.14.1 
  │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
  │ │   ├── getpass@0.1.6 
  │ │   ├── jodid25519@1.0.2 
  │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.0 
  │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.14.3 
  │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0 
  │ ├── isstream@0.1.2 
  │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
  │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.13 
  │ │ └── mime-db@1.25.0 
  │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2 
  │ ├── qs@6.3.0 
  │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5 
  │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@2.3.2 
  │ │ └── punycode@1.4.1 
  │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.3 
  ├── retry@0.10.1 
  ├── rimraf@2.5.4 
  ├── semver@5.3.0 
  ├── sha@2.0.1 
  ├── slide@1.1.6 
  ├── sorted-object@2.0.1 
  ├─┬ sorted-union-stream@2.1.3 
  │ ├─┬ from2@1.3.0 
  │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.14 
  │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
  │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1 
  │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
  │ └── stream-iterate@1.1.1 
  ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1 
  ├─┬ tar@2.2.1 
  │ └── block-stream@0.0.8 
  ├── text-table@0.2.0 
  ├── uid-number@0.0.6 
  ├── umask@1.1.0 
  ├─┬ unique-filename@1.1.0 
  │ └── unique-slug@2.0.0 
  ├── unpipe@1.0.0 
  ├── uuid@3.0.1 
  ├─┬ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1 
  │ ├─┬ spdx-correct@1.0.2 
  │ │ └── spdx-license-ids@1.2.0 
  │ └─┬ spdx-expression-parse@1.0.2 
  │   ├── spdx-exceptions@1.0.4 
  │   └── spdx-license-ids@1.2.0 
  ├─┬ validate-npm-package-name@2.2.2 
  │ └── builtins@0.0.7 
  ├─┬ which@1.2.12 
  │ └── isexe@1.1.2 
  ├── wrappy@1.0.2 
  └── write-file-atomic@1.3.1
```

I then attempted to run `node .` and received the following error

```
MacBook-Pro:marketing-notifications-node-master $USER$ node .
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/$USER/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:8:52)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

**EDIT**
I tried deleting and reclining the original project file. I did `npm install` and received this output:

```
 npm install
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated mongodb@1.4.12: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use @segment/to-iso-string instead.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> kerberos@0.0.4 install /Users/$USER/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> bson@0.2.22 install /Users/$USER/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

sms-notifications-node@1.0.0 /Users/$USER/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master
├─┬ body-parser@1.17.1 
│ ├── bytes@2.4.0 
│ ├── content-type@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ debug@2.6.1 
│ │ └── ms@0.7.2 
│ ├── depd@1.1.0 
│ ├─┬ http-errors@1.6.1 
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.3 
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.15 
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
│ ├── qs@6.4.0 
│ ├─┬ raw-body@2.2.0 
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ type-is@1.6.14 
│   ├── media-typer@0.3.0 
│   └─┬ mime-types@2.1.14 
│     └── mime-db@1.26.0 
├─┬ chai@2.3.0 
│ ├── assertion-error@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ deep-eql@0.1.3 
│   └── type-detect@0.1.1 
├── connect-flash@0.1.1 
├─┬ express@4.15.2 
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.3 
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1 
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.2 
│ ├── cookie@0.3.1 
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
│ ├── encodeurl@1.0.1 
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
│ ├── etag@1.8.0 
│ ├── finalhandler@1.0.0 
│ ├── fresh@0.5.0 
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
│ ├── methods@1.1.2 
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.1 
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.1.3 
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0 
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.2.0 
│ ├── range-parser@1.2.0 
│ ├─┬ send@0.15.1 
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4 
│ │ └── mime@1.3.4 
│ ├── serve-static@1.12.1 
│ ├── setprototypeof@1.0.3 
│ ├── statuses@1.3.1 
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0 
│ └── vary@1.1.0 
├─┬ express-session@1.15.1 
│ ├── crc@3.4.4 
│ ├── on-headers@1.0.1 
│ └─┬ uid-safe@2.1.4 
│   └── random-bytes@1.0.0 
├─┬ http-auth@2.4.11 
│ ├─┬ apache-crypt@1.1.2 
│ │ └── unix-crypt-td-js@1.0.0 
│ ├── apache-md5@1.0.6 
│ └── node-uuid@1.4.7 
├─┬ jade@1.11.0 
│ ├── character-parser@1.2.1 
│ ├─┬ clean-css@3.4.25 
│ │ ├─┬ commander@2.8.1 
│ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
│ │ └─┬ source-map@0.4.4 
│ │   └── amdefine@1.0.1 
│ ├── commander@2.6.0 
│ ├─┬ constantinople@3.0.2 
│ │ └── acorn@2.7.0 
│ ├─┬ jstransformer@0.0.2 
│ │ ├── is-promise@2.1.0 
│ │ └─┬ promise@6.1.0 
│ │   └── asap@1.0.0 
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0 
│ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8 
│ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4 
│ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5 
│ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0 
│ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.1 
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5 
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7 
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3 
│ │   └── source-map@0.1.43 
│ ├─┬ uglify-js@2.8.8 
│ │ ├── source-map@0.5.6 
│ │ ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
│ │ └─┬ yargs@3.10.0 
│ │   ├── camelcase@1.2.1 
│ │   ├─┬ cliui@2.1.0 
│ │   │ ├─┬ center-align@0.1.3 
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ align-text@0.1.4 
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ kind-of@3.1.0 
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.4 
│ │   │ │ │ ├── longest@1.0.1 
│ │   │ │ │ └── repeat-string@1.6.1 
│ │   │ │ └── lazy-cache@1.0.4 
│ │   │ ├── right-align@0.1.3 
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2 
│ │   ├── decamelize@1.2.0 
│ │   └── window-size@0.1.0 
│ ├── void-elements@2.0.1 
│ └─┬ with@4.0.3 
│   ├── acorn@1.2.2 
│   └── acorn-globals@1.0.9 
├─┬ mocha@2.5.3 
│ ├── commander@2.3.0 
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0 
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1 
│ ├── diff@1.4.0 
│ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11 
│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0 
│ │   ├── lru-cache@2.7.3 
│ │   └── sigmund@1.0.1 
│ ├── growl@1.9.2 
│ ├─┬ jade@0.26.3 
│ │ ├── commander@0.6.1 
│ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ ├── supports-color@1.2.0 
│ └── to-iso-string@0.0.2 
├─┬ mongoose@3.9.7 
│ ├── async@0.9.0 
│ ├── hooks@0.3.2 
│ ├── kareem@0.0.4 
│ ├─┬ mongodb@1.4.12 
│ │ ├─┬ bson@0.2.22 
│ │ │ └── nan@1.8.4 
│ │ ├── kerberos@0.0.4 
│ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.2.3 
│ │   ├── buffer-shims@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
│ │   ├── isarray@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
│ │   ├── string_decoder@0.10.31 
│ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
│ ├── mpath@0.1.1 
│ ├── mpromise@0.5.4 
│ ├─┬ mquery@1.0.0 
│ │ └── debug@0.7.4 
│ ├── ms@0.1.0 
│ ├── muri@0.3.1 
│ ├── regexp-clone@0.0.1 
│ └── sliced@0.0.5 
├─┬ morgan@1.8.1 
│ └── basic-auth@1.1.0 
└─┬ twilio@1.11.1 
  ├── jwt-simple@0.1.0 
  ├── q@0.9.7 
  ├─┬ request@2.27.0 
  │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0 
  │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0 
  │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2 
  │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4 
  │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7 
  │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5 
  │ │ └── mime@1.2.11 
  │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2 
  │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2 
  │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1 
  │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4 
  │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.1 
  │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11 
  │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.5 
  │ │ └── ctype@0.5.3 
  │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
  │ ├── mime@1.2.11 
  │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0 
  │ ├── qs@0.6.6 
  │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0 
  ├── scmp@0.0.3 
  └── underscore@1.8.3
```

I then tried to run `node .` and received the error:

```
MacBook-Pro:marketing-notifications-node-master $USER$ node .
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/$USER/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:8:52)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

**EDIT**
I've attempted to use `npm install -g node-gyp` then `npm install mongoose@3.9.7`

`npm install -g node-gyp` gave an output of :

`MacBook-Pro:marketing-notifications-node-master $USER$ npm install -g node-gyp
/Users/$USER/.npm-packages/bin/node-gyp -> /Users/$USER/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
/Users/$USER/.npm-packages/lib
└── node-gyp@3.5.0`

`MacBook-Pro:marketing-notifications-node-master $USER$ npm install mongoose@3.9.7
npm WARN deprecated mongodb@1.4.12: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher
sms-notifications-node@1.0.0 /Users/$USER/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master
└── mongoose@3.9.7`

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in the application directory?

Comment: Yup, i've tried that multiple times.

Comment: And does it complete successfully? It looks as though the bson module (which is depended on my the mongodb module, which mongoose needs) has failed to install. If you just run `npm install bson` what happens?

Comment: 'MacBook-Pro:node_modules $USER$ npm install bson
sms-notifications-node@1.0.0 /Users/$user/Desktop/marketing-notifications-node-master
└── (empty)

npm ERR! code 1

Comment: Could you edit your question with the whole error message please?

Comment: ' MacBook-Pro:~ $user$ npm install bson
/Users/$USER
└── bson@1.0.4 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/derrickskipper/package.json'
npm WARN $USER No description
npm WARN $USER No repository field.
npm WARN $USER No README data
npm WARN $USER No license field.
'

Comment: Hold on! It's only worth running these commands in the directory of the project.

Comment: That was the whole error message that I received back from Terminal

Comment: What version of Node and npm do you have? (`node --version` and `npm --version`)

Comment: node - 6.10.0 and npm 3.10.10

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm going to try to solve this outside of the comments as that is going to be difficult.

It looks as though you are having problems installing your dependencies. From [this issue on npm's GitHub project](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10431) the suggestion is to run:

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Then try to run your full `npm install` again and if that works, run `node .`. Do all of this inside your project directory. If it doesn't work, please update your question with any error messages and I will try again!

**Edit** my output from npm install

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated mongodb@1.4.12: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use @segment/to-iso-string instead.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> kerberos@0.0.4 install /Users/pnash/projects/node-projects/marketing-notifications-node/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o

> bson@0.2.22 install /Users/pnash/projects/node-projects/marketing-notifications-node/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
sms-notifications-node@1.0.0 /Users/pnash/projects/node-projects/marketing-notifications-node
├─┬ body-parser@1.17.1 
│ ├── bytes@2.4.0 
│ ├── content-type@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ debug@2.6.1 
│ │ └── ms@0.7.2 
│ ├── depd@1.1.0 
│ ├─┬ http-errors@1.6.1 
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.3 
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.15 
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
│ ├── qs@6.4.0 
│ ├─┬ raw-body@2.2.0 
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ type-is@1.6.14 
│   ├── media-typer@0.3.0 
│   └─┬ mime-types@2.1.14 
│     └── mime-db@1.26.0 
├─┬ chai@2.3.0 
│ ├── assertion-error@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ deep-eql@0.1.3 
│   └── type-detect@0.1.1 
├── connect-flash@0.1.1 
├─┬ express@4.15.2 
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.3 
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1 
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.2 
│ ├── cookie@0.3.1 
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
│ ├── encodeurl@1.0.1 
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
│ ├── etag@1.8.0 
│ ├── finalhandler@1.0.0 
│ ├── fresh@0.5.0 
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
│ ├── methods@1.1.2 
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.1 
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.1.3 
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0 
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.2.0 
│ ├── range-parser@1.2.0 
│ ├─┬ send@0.15.1 
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4 
│ │ └── mime@1.3.4 
│ ├── serve-static@1.12.1 
│ ├── setprototypeof@1.0.3 
│ ├── statuses@1.3.1 
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0 
│ └── vary@1.1.0 
├─┬ express-session@1.15.1 
│ ├── crc@3.4.4 
│ ├── on-headers@1.0.1 
│ └─┬ uid-safe@2.1.4 
│   └── random-bytes@1.0.0 
├─┬ http-auth@2.4.11 
│ ├─┬ apache-crypt@1.1.2 
│ │ └── unix-crypt-td-js@1.0.0 
│ ├── apache-md5@1.0.6 
│ └── node-uuid@1.4.7 
├─┬ jade@1.11.0 
│ ├── character-parser@1.2.1 
│ ├─┬ clean-css@3.4.25 
│ │ ├─┬ commander@2.8.1 
│ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
│ │ └─┬ source-map@0.4.4 
│ │   └── amdefine@1.0.1 
│ ├── commander@2.6.0 
│ ├─┬ constantinople@3.0.2 
│ │ └── acorn@2.7.0 
│ ├─┬ jstransformer@0.0.2 
│ │ ├── is-promise@2.1.0 
│ │ └─┬ promise@6.1.0 
│ │   └── asap@1.0.0 
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0 
│ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8 
│ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4 
│ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5 
│ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0 
│ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.1 
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5 
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7 
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3 
│ │   └── source-map@0.1.43 
│ ├─┬ uglify-js@2.8.8 
│ │ ├── source-map@0.5.6 
│ │ ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
│ │ └─┬ yargs@3.10.0 
│ │   ├── camelcase@1.2.1 
│ │   ├─┬ cliui@2.1.0 
│ │   │ ├─┬ center-align@0.1.3 
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ align-text@0.1.4 
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ kind-of@3.1.0 
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.4 
│ │   │ │ │ ├── longest@1.0.1 
│ │   │ │ │ └── repeat-string@1.6.1 
│ │   │ │ └── lazy-cache@1.0.4 
│ │   │ ├── right-align@0.1.3 
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2 
│ │   ├── decamelize@1.2.0 
│ │   └── window-size@0.1.0 
│ ├── void-elements@2.0.1 
│ └─┬ with@4.0.3 
│   ├── acorn@1.2.2 
│   └── acorn-globals@1.0.9 
├─┬ mocha@2.5.3 
│ ├── commander@2.3.0 
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0 
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1 
│ ├── diff@1.4.0 
│ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11 
│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0 
│ │   ├── lru-cache@2.7.3 
│ │   └── sigmund@1.0.1 
│ ├── growl@1.9.2 
│ ├─┬ jade@0.26.3 
│ │ ├── commander@0.6.1 
│ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ ├── supports-color@1.2.0 
│ └── to-iso-string@0.0.2 
├─┬ mongoose@3.9.7 
│ ├── async@0.9.0 
│ ├── hooks@0.3.2 
│ ├── kareem@0.0.4 
│ ├─┬ mongodb@1.4.12 
│ │ ├─┬ bson@0.2.22 
│ │ │ └── nan@1.8.4 
│ │ ├── kerberos@0.0.4 
│ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.2.3 
│ │   ├── buffer-shims@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
│ │   ├── isarray@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
│ │   ├── string_decoder@0.10.31 
│ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
│ ├── mpath@0.1.1 
│ ├── mpromise@0.5.4 
│ ├─┬ mquery@1.0.0 
│ │ └── debug@0.7.4 
│ ├── ms@0.1.0 
│ ├── muri@0.3.1 
│ ├── regexp-clone@0.0.1 
│ └── sliced@0.0.5 
├─┬ morgan@1.8.1 
│ └── basic-auth@1.1.0 
└─┬ twilio@1.11.1 
  ├── jwt-simple@0.1.0 
  ├── q@0.9.7 
  ├─┬ request@2.27.0 
  │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0 
  │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0 
  │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2 
  │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4 
  │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7 
  │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5 
  │ │ └── mime@1.2.11 
  │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2 
  │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2 
  │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1 
  │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4 
  │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.1 
  │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11 
  │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.5 
  │ │ └── ctype@0.5.3 
  │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
  │ ├── mime@1.2.11 
  │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0 
  │ ├── qs@0.6.6 
  │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0 
  ├── scmp@0.0.3 
  └── underscore@1.8.3
```

Comment: I just updated it. I really appreciate that you're helping me out.

Comment: Can you include all the output you see from `npm install` please?

Comment: I don't get an output when I run ' npm install '. It shows that it's installing and then it finishes and gives me a clean command line.

Comment: I see what you mean now. One second.

Comment: I've added my output from npm install to the answer above. Do you have a setting in npm where you have turned output like that off? You may be hiding important warnings.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I added the output to the original post. I'm not sure how i'd go about changing the output.

Comment: Which directory did you run `npm install` from to get that output?

Comment: This is after I followed your instructions to do npm cache clean & npm install -g npm@latest and then npm install. I did this all in my project directory

Comment: It's just weird, if you look at the first few things your npm install has (abbrev, ansi-regex, ansicolors, etc) they are totally different to my output (body-parser, bytes, content-type). My output definitely comes from the package.json that I have in the project (dependencies also starts with body-parser) but I don't know where yours comes from. Maybe try starting again, remove the entire `marketing-notifications-node-master` folder and reclone it from GitHub, then `cd` into the new file, run `npm install` and show me the output from that.

Comment: I am consulting with the team who wrote this application to see if they have any ideas. Currently I don't know what's going on any more!

Comment: lol welcome aboard the uss clueless. I've been through all of the boards twice over.

Comment: You're definitely still more knowledgeable than me but I appreciate your help. It's just sad that i'm stuck on the set up.

Comment: I understand, I'll let you know if I can get any more help from the team here. One more thing, can you try (again, in the project directory) `npm install -g node-gyp` then `npm install mongoose@3.9.7` and let me know the output?